# Convert "character" matrix to "logical"

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (with values of `class` `character` like this one:

```
mat <- matrix(c("0", "TRUE", "1", "2",
                "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "2"), nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
#> mat
#     [,1]   [,2]   
#[1,] "0"    "FALSE"
#[2,] "TRUE" "TRUE" 
#[3,] "1"    "TRUE" 
#[4,] "2"    "2"
```

and I need to convert it to a matrix like this:

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

`as.logical` outputs `NA`s to "character-numeric" values, whereas `as.numeric` outputs `NA`s to "character-logical" values.

I found a solution but I think I'm missing something clearly obvious as to an immediate conversion:

```
new_mat2 <- array(as.numeric(mat), dim(mat))
new_mat <- array(as.logical(mat), dim(mat))

new_mat[is.na(new_mat)] <- new_mat2[is.na(new_mat)]
mat2 <- array(as.logical(new_mat), dim(new_mat))

#> mat2
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
> mat[,] <- ifelse(mat %in% c("0", "FALSE"), FALSE, TRUE) # pay attention to @Señor O comment to shorten this step.
> mat
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "FALSE" "FALSE"
[2,] "TRUE"  "TRUE" 
[3,] "TRUE"  "TRUE" 
[4,] "TRUE"  "TRUE"
```

If you want `mat` to be a data.frame consisting of logical values, then:

```
> mat <- sapply(as.data.frame(mat), as.logical)
> mat
        V1    V2
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
> sapply(mat, class)  # checking class
[1] "logical" "logical" "logical" "logical" "logical" "logical" "logical" "logical"
```

Comment: How about just `mat[,] <- !mat %in% c("0", "FALSE")`?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of manipulating `%in%` this way! I'll accept it, although -to tell the truth- I was hoping for something that I hadn't notice (but should have) in a function or help page of `R` on this subject. Don't let my acceptance, though, discourage you of giving any insight if you have! :) Thanks, again!

Answer (score 3):

`NA` is a logical constant therefore it has truth table laws it must obey. We can exploit these to do...

```
mat2 <- as.logical(mat) & ( as.integer(mat) > 0 )
mat2[is.na(mat2)] <- TRUE
dim(mat2) <- dim(mat)
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

This works *only* if you do not have `NA` in your original matrix, because we rely on being `NA` itself a logical constant. If a given value is `FALSE`, `as.logical` will evaulate to `TRUE`, but cannot also (`&`) be `as.integer`, so will give `FALSE`. If it is `"0"` `as.logical` will evaluate to `NA`, whilst `as.integer > 0` will evaluate to `FALSE`. `NA` & `FALSE` evaluates to `FALSE`. The two FALSE conditions are met, therefore remaining `NA` *must* be `TRUE`.

Comment: I'm really thankful for the insight on the "`NA` as logical" thing; it never did occur to me as a need. I waited eagerly for an answer like "did you know that..". :) Thanks!

Comment: @alexis_laz you're welcome. You have to be careful with `NA` though. There are some truth tables at the bottom of the help page on logical operators ( try `?\`!\`` )

Comment: this also loses the dimnames

Comment: @JeremyLeipzig it wasn't part of the OP, but if say the matrix `mat` in the question *did* have names which you wanted to preserve after the transformation it is as simple as `dimnames( mat2 ) <- dimnames( mat )` since the matrix has the same dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

mat != "0" & mat != "FALSE"

```
> mat
     [,1]   [,2]   
[1,] "0"    "FALSE"
[2,] "TRUE" "TRUE" 
[3,] "1"    "TRUE" 
[4,] "2"    "2"    

> mat != "0" & mat != "FALSE"
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct I know would be:

`as.numeric(factor(matrix))`

where 'matrix' is the name of the matrix we want to change to numeric